# iText is slow also by providing fonts

Tags: performance, pdf, itext

I provided css and fonts to iText as specified in https://developers.itextpdf.com/fr/node/2085: for this I installed arial.ttf on a directory. I provided also a css where I stated that Arial is the official font for all

```
h1 {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 24px;
font-style: bold;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 26.4px;
}
h2 {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: bold;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 22.4px;
}
h3 {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: bold;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 15.4px;
}
body {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 20px;
}
p {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

but my server spent 2 minutes to create a pdf from a simple html page. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You refer to a FAQ entry about XML Worker. This means that you're probably using iText 5. Why aren't you using iText 7 and the [pdfHTML add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML)? Read [the intro of the PDF to HTML tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) to understand the history and evolution of HTML parsing with iText. iText 5 and XML Worker are no longer supported in favor of iText 7 and the pdfHTML add-on.

Comment: Also: why do you think that fonts are the culprit? Maybe your HTML contains images that need to be fetched from a slow network. If that is the case, you are wasting the time of anyone trying to help you by making the wrong diagnosis. You should provide more info (e.g. an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) so that people can check if your allegation is correct.

Comment: I'm using this version from Maven compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13' that is the last on Maven. In my text there are not images.

Comment: The question is incomplete, your HTML and your Java code is missing. Installation instructions, including Maven versions, are on https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java

Comment: Your allegation "that is the last on Maven" isn't correct. 5.5.13 is a *maintenance* release. Development on versions 5.5.x has stopped. We only make releases with bug fixes for paying customers who can't migrate to iText 7 yet. It is strongly advised to move to iText 7 which is the *current* release. See https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java and you'll notice that there's a 7.1 on Maven, and if my Math skills are still intact 7.1 is higher than 5.5.

Comment: Now I'm using iText 7, also in this case is slow, my doubt is that html have problema because it contains tags with style like this <span style="font-size:12px;"> </span>. Calling code is very simple :    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
     properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
   HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(html, outStream); and there is only an image with a complete URL source. It works on my development environment but on my server is very slow: I have a log when it starts and a log at the end of trasformation.